# help in perl regex using command line

Tags: regex, perl, command-line, command

I have regex expression:

```
echo "(1508,'2011-02-28','pc','postroll','ai-postroll','HT','','',16),(1508,'2011-02-28','pc','postroll','ai-postroll','MU','','',11),(1508," | perl -pe "s|,(\d+)\)|,'',($1)\)|g"
```

I am trying to replace the number before closing parenthesis with an extra value.
So '',16) would be replaced by ,'',''16) .

I am finding issue that $1 is not getting replaced.Please let me know what is that I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you used double-quotes, bash will try to substitute a value for $1.  Try replacing it with \$1.